# Only nonzero values Python list

Tags: python-2.7

I want to Extract only nonzero numbers from python list .
This is what I am doing . but it isnt working it seems .

```
d=[num if num for num in d]
```

> where d is my original list and again I want output in same list

Comment: Show us the input, output and what is your expected output - because it seems that nobody understands your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d = [num for num in d if num]
```

**EDIT**

According to your comment below, by "extracting non-zero" you mean: "the way to map 0 and nonzero numbers from a list:

```
d = [num if num else 0 for num in d]
```

another way:

```
d = map(lambda x: 1 if x else 0, d)
```

Comment: Yeah I know this way , But i was wondering why this isnt working .. 
`d=[1 if num else 0 for num in d]` if this is the way to map 0 and nonzero numbers from a list.. why the above way doesnt work just to ignore nonzero numbers ?

Comment: @Hima, you are not doing it that way in your question, your syntax is not valid. Doing as you have in your comment, your else clause then  would add to your list when num was 0. You just want an `if num` check at the end of your code

Comment: Thanks for the update . what I want to say is why its like sometimes if clause works like `[1 if num else 0 for num in d]` but when you just want to extract nonzero elements you have to use if clause like this . `[num for num in d if num]` ... these are two different ways..
but what i think is  `[num if num for num in d ]` should work.. if it works in case of mapping.. (both are different but similar problems but why two ways ! ) .. sorry I am stretching it .. but i was just wondering ..

Comment: @Hima not sure if I got what you meant, but you can also do: `d =[num if num else 0 for num in d]` or `d =[1 if num else 0 for num in d]`

Answer (score 3):

```
In [5]: d =[1,2,3,0,0,9]

In [6]: d = filter(None,d) 

In [7]: d
Out[7]: [1, 2, 3, 9]
```

Some timings:

```
In [30]: %timeit filter(None,d)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 727 ns per loop

In [31]: %timeit filter(lambda x: x != 0, d)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.89 µs per loop

In [32]: %timeit [x for x in d if x != 0]
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.33 µs per loop

In [33]: %timeit  [num for num in d if num]
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.04 µs per loop
```

As you only have numbers in your list `filter(None,d)` will work fine. If you had any other falsey values like empty lists `[]` etc.. it would also remove them.

Answer (score 1):

Try any of these:

```
d = [x for x in d if x != 0]

d = filter(lambda x: x != 0, d)

d = [x for x in d if x]
```

Comment: python does not treat 0 as False?

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. You just have to fix the list comprehension "syntax":

```
d = [num for num in d if num]
```

**Note:** This is possible because Python treats `0` as `False`.